# How to calculate a price based on time passed in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

I'm currently working on an app that calculates the price a user has to pay for a service based on how much time he's spent using said service. The fee is $3.30 for the first hour and then $1.15 for every half hour after that. My timer looks something like this:

```
    private void timer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        timer.Tick +=
            delegate(object s, EventArgs args)
            {
                TimeSpan time = (DateTime.Now - StartTime);

                this.Time.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
            };
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // one second
        timer.Start();
    }
```

The point being that the timer AND the price to pay should be shown on screen and update automatically with the passing of time (the timer already does that.)

As for the price itself, I thought of using a combination of if/else and foreach, but so far, I've accomplished nothing...

Comment: You start by defining the problem better: what happens for partial hours?

Comment: Yes I did, my mistake. The additional 1.15 gets added as soon as the next time segment starts (30 minutes)

Comment: What happens if StartTime is just before the "spring forward" moment of Daylight Savings Time? Is the user then charged for the fake hour that is inserted?  What if StartTime is just before the "fall back" moment, and they use the service for less than an hour? Are they charged for negative time?  What if the user is on a laptop and changes time zones? Are they charged for the positive or negative hours induced by the changed time zone?

Comment: @EricLippert very nice observations. Even though the context of my app is simple, and it would be very unlikely that the DST moments happened while in use, it's still good practice to foresee such scenarios and code accordingly. I'm gonna go with the UTC solution provided in the comments below, possibly implement it in a server in the furure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scheme is such that the cost is added as soon as a segment starts then you can calculate the number of half hours that have started, after the initial hour, as:

```
Math.Round((hours - 1) / 0.5 + 0.5)
```

And the cost is then calculated as:

```
double hours = (DateTime.UtcNow - StartTime).TotalHours;
double cost;
if (hours < 1)
    cost = 3.30;
else
    cost = 3.30 + Math.Round((hours - 1) / 0.5 + 0.5) * 1.15;
```

Comment: This one seems to be working. I added another DispatcherTimer to update the price by using your method every few seconds and it's all looking good.

Comment: @iVikD Why don't you use the same timer for both?

Comment: Great :) You should consider the Eric Lippert's points in the comments above to ensure the stability of your system. For instance, use Universal Time when comparing dates and consider perhaps doing sensitive calculations on the server.

Comment: @svick stupid of me to overlook that, thanks for pointing it out. odyss-jii, Thanks for the tips as well, it's working like a charm!

Comment: `Math.Round` is a bit convoluted, bankers round has a funny effect(even if it's not relevant in practice), and money should be represented by `decimal` not `double`. Finally this code is hard to test.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. (You left out how partial hours are handled so I ignored them.)

```
double span = (DateTime.Now - StartTime).TotalHours;
decimal cost = 0.0;
if (span > 0)
    cost = 3.30 + ((span - 1) * 1.15);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1. Use UTC times, not local times (See Eric Lippert's comment)
2. Use `decimal` and not `double` to represent money
3. To calculate started time intervals, `Math.Ceiling` is great. No need to jump through hoops to get `Math.Round` to do what you want.
4. Encapsulate your pricing logic into a simple side-effect free method that doesn't interact with external services, such as the clock.

   This makes it easy to test the method in isolation.
5. Use a single timer for all periodic UI updates (unless they require different intervals)

I'd write it like this:

```
public decimal CostByTime(TimeSpan t)
{
  if(t < TimeSpan.Zero)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeExeception("t", "Requires t>=0");
  if(t ==  TimeSpan.Zero)
      return 0;
  double hours = t.TotalHours;
  if(hours <= 1)
      return 3.30m;
  else
      return 3.30m + (int)Math.Ceiling((hours-1)*2) * 1.15m
}
```

And then in your view you can use:

```
TimeSpan billableTime = DateTime.UtcNow - StartTime;
decimal cost = CostByTime(billableTime);

Time.Text = billableTime.ToString(...);
Cost.Text = cost.ToString();
```

Comment: The first hour costs 3.30, not 2.30. The commented code is thus not equivalent to `Math.Ceiling(hours*2) * 1.15m`.